# Compute $A^{1/2}$ where $A$ is a matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&2&2\\ 2&1&2\\2&2&1\end{pmatrix}$. We define $A^{1/2}$ as the matrix $B$ s.t. $B^2=A$. What I did is I set $B=\begin{pmatrix}a&b&c\\d&e&f\\g&h&i\end{pmatrix}$, and I tried to solve the system $B^2=A$, but it's rather impossible. Is there a trick ?

Comment: The usual approach is to diagonalize $A$

Comment: There can be lots of matrices $B$ such that $B^2 = A$. What one usually does for symmetric, positive-definite $A$ is to diagonalise $A = PDP^{-1}$ where $D$ is diagonal with positive entries. Then it's clear that $B = P\sqrt{D}P^{-1}$ satisfies $B^2 = A$, where $\sqrt{D}$ is the element-wise square root of the matrix $D$.

Answer (score 1):

I just give the argument : Let $P$ the matrix s.t. $PAP^{-1}=D$ is diagonal. Then $\sqrt D$ is very easy to calculate. Then $$(PBP^{-1})^2=PB^2P^{-1}=D,$$
which implies that $$PBP^{-1}=\sqrt D\implies B=P^{-1}\sqrt DP.$$

Answer (score 1):

Here is a nice trick that is straightforward to use, but difficult to justify in an elementary way. Define
$$
P = \pmatrix{1&1&1\\1&1&1\\1&1&1}, \quad I = \pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1}
$$
We have $A = 2P - I$.  I claim that there exist complex numbers $x,y$ such that
$$
(xP + yI)^2 = 2P - I = A
$$
By distributing the left side, we end up with
$$
(xP + yI)^2 = x^2P^2 + (x+y)P + y^2 I =
x^2 \cdot 3P + (x+y)P + y^2 I =\\
(3x^2 + x + y)P + y^2 I
$$
So, it suffices to find $x,y$ such that
$$
y^2 = -1,\\
3x^2 + x = 2 - y.
$$

Comment: so the entries of $A^{1/2}$ may be not in $\Bbb R$

Comment: Indeed; it is unclear whether OP wants a matrix with real entries.  Keep in mind, however, that $A^{1/2}$ is not unique.  In fact, in this case $A$ does admit a real square root since the only negative eigenvalue has even multiplicity.  Such a square root cannot be written in the form of the linear combination I present, though.

Answer (score 0):

The matrix $A$ is written as $A = J - I$, where $J$ is the matrix full of $2$'s, and $I$ is the identity matrix. The matrix $J$ has two eigenspaces: its one-dimensional eigenspace is spanned by the vector $v = (1, 1, 1)$, and its two-dimensional eigenspace $W$ consists of those vectors $w = (a, b, c)$ such that $a + b + c = 0$.

Now $Av = 5v$, and $Aw = -w$ for any $w \in W$. So it is reasonable to define $B$ such that $Bv = \sqrt{5} v$, and $B$ acts as a 90-degree rotation on $W$. It's also reasonable to define $B$ such that $B$ acts on $W$ as multiplication by $\sqrt{-1}$, if you are allowed complex entries.